# How can I download a json Dataframe in Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I've been working with a dataframe in google colab, and i convert it to a json format using df.to_json(), now i stuck on how to download it into my local disk (or google drive). i found the answers but in csv format, not json.

Any help is appreciated - thanks!

Comment: You should edit your question to include your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can proceed in steps: 1) save the output of `to_json()` to a file on the Colab backend. Then, use the built-in download helper

from google.colab import files
files.download('colab_file_name')

Here's a complete example that starts with a randomly generated DataFrame:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1K95vU0gUJW4iJ4FaHxZ1HSQguOP1flEg